# How can I increase the height of the outer brace?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax, mathml

How can I increase the height of the outer brace? Is there any way in MathML or MathJax?

```
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">&#x0028;</mo>
    <mspace width="0.15em"/>
    <mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">&#x0028;</mo>
        <mspace width="0.15em"/>
        <mrow>
          <mn>1</mn>
          <mo>+</mo>
          <mn>21</mn>
          <mo>+</mo>
          <mn>2</mn>
        </mrow>
        <mspace width="0.15em"/>
        <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">&#x0029;</mo>
      </mrow>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mn>21</mn>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mn>21</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mspace width="0.15em"/>
    <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">&#x0029;</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

Image:

[image]

Is this possible in MathML or MathJax?
If not, any better solution using CSS or Javascript?

**EDIT**
This is just a sample expression. My expression can have multiple braces at multiple levels. So if there are 3 braces, outer brace must be larger than middle brace and middle brace must be larger than inner brace.

Comment: you can add inline css in our outer brace tag style="font-size:20px;"

Comment: This is a sample expression, my expression can contain multiple braces at multiple levels. Will this work if there are three braces.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5tSB/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Fails for multiple level braces. If there are 3 braces second brace must be larger than inner brace, and outer brace must be larger than second brace. This brace level is not fixed, it will be dynamic.

Comment: @Mr.Alien looks prefect

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe check http://jsfiddle.net/Y5tSB/1/, this is using same css provided by Mr.Alien

Comment: @madhu_p I coded as per your title said, rest of the conditions you should state in your question

Comment: @Mr.Alien agreed, but unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. Updated my question with more details.

Comment: Note that if you want to use MathJax to handle the display of the MathML, then you can't use CSS to style the MathML (as MathJax will replace the MathML by HTML tags rather than MathML, so they will not be properly styled).  Also, changing the font size of the parentheses will lead to poor typeset quality, as they will be the wrong weight (they will appear too bold) and they won't be centered on the math axis correctly.  It is best to use MathML attributes like `minsize` rather than CSS font size.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `minsize="1.2"` (or some other factor) to the stretchy `<mo>` to force it to be at least 1.2 times as large as its natural size.  For example

```
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="true" stretchy="true" minsize="1.2">&#x0028;</mo>
    <mspace width="0.15em"/>
    <mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">&#x0028;</mo>
        <mspace width="0.15em"/>
        <mrow>
          <mn>1</mn>
          <mo>+</mo>
          <mn>21</mn>
          <mo>+</mo>
          <mn>2</mn>
        </mrow>
        <mspace width="0.15em"/>
        <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">&#x0029;</mo>
      </mrow>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mn>21</mn>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mn>21</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mspace width="0.15em"/>
    <mo fence="true" stretchy="true" minsize="1.2">&#x0029;</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

should make the he outer parentheses larger.